# RabbitMq: "None of the specified endpoints were reachable"

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm a newbie in RabbitMQ. I got a message when I try to connect to RabbitMQ from another machine: "None of the specified endpoints were reachable". Although I created user/password, allowed firewall for port 15672, but I still got error.

My code here:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory();

factory.HostName = "192.168.20.30";

factory.UserName = "user";

factory.Password = "password";

factory.Port = 15672;

factory.VirtualHost = "/";

var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

What did I do something wrong?

Comment: 15672 is the port for Management Console for establishing the AMQP connection you should use the port 5672

Comment: @ Soumen Mukherjee, thank you. I did as you advised and it ran.

Answer (score 2):

15672 is the port for Management Console for establishing the AMQP connection you should use the port 5672.